# How to put default value in EditText in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to put a value in `EditText` but I can not.

The code I edit:

```
<EditText android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/input_username" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" android:hint="@string/input_username_hint" 
    android:ems="10" android:singleLine="true" android:maxLength="140" 
    android:layout_below="@id/input_room_name" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

When I put `android:text="user"` the genarated apk is not opening.

Comment: Please explain what "not opening" means. If you mean that you are crashing, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
editText.setText("Your default text");
```

But if you want to show that gray text that disappears when the user starts to type, you're looking for `android:hint`.

On xml:

```
android:hint="Your default text"
```

On java:

```
editText.setHint("Your default text");
```

On kotlin:

```
editText.hint = "Your default text"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your .xml file,

specify

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="user" />
```

or

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="user" />
```

If you want to do it in program

do this

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
et.setText("user");
```

or

```
et.setHint("user");
```